# JavaScript - Uncaught ReferenceError: {funcao} is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Olá, meus amigos! Boa noite!

Sou iniciante em JavaScript e estou diante da seguinte situação: 
Tenho um script chamado *widget.js* em minha página inicial e este script realiza uma requisição em busca de um html "complementar", numa segunda página chamada *widget.php*. 
Nesta segunda página (widget.php) eu tenho um função JavaScript.

O problema é o seguinte... Quando eu faço a requisição com *XMLHttpRequest*, tudo que preciso (html e js) são colocados em minha página inicial (posso ver inspecionando), mas a função me retorna o seguinte erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: teste is not defined

Ou seja, a função vinda do widget.php é escrita, mas não é executada. Segue o resumão do meu código:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<script async="" src="https://meusite.com/widget.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**widget.js**

```
url = 'https://meusite.com/widget.php';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) { 
        var resp = this.response; 
        var el = document.querySelector('body');
        var html = '<div>'+resp+'</div>';
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);  
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
```

**widget.php**

```
<h1>Título</h1>
<p>Descrição</p>
<button onclick="teste();">Ok</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function teste() {
        alert('Ok!');
    } 
</script>
```

Seguem as imagens de retorno.

**Ao carregar:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Após chamar a função manualmente:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma coisa importante: não posso usar jQuery. Inclusive, já testei com ele e funciona muito bem. Precisa ser com JavaScript puro mesmo. Também já testei com innerHTML e eval(), e não consegui fazer funcionar.

Então é isso, pessoal. Alguém sabe por que isso está acontecendo e como posso solucionar?
Muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: Na tag `<script type="text/javascript">` retire o atributo `type="text/javascript"` em HTML5 basta `<script>`

Comment: Muda a forma de importação desses arquivos mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você carrega um trecho de script via AJAX, ele é incluído no DOM mas não é carregado na memória do JS, portanto o código não é executado e as funções não existem. O que você pode fazer é verificar se no retorno do AJAX possui tags `<scripts>` e inserir na página através do `document.createElement("script")`. Através desse método, o script é carregado na memória.

Só que me vez de usar `var html = '<div>'+resp+'</div>';` para montar a nova div, use `var html = document.createElement("div");` para criar a div e insira a resposta do AJAX através o `.innerHTML` nessa div e em seguida insira tudo na página com `el.appendChild(html);`.

```
var html = document.createElement("div"); //  cria a div
html.innerHTML = resp; // insere na div a resposta do AJAX
el.appendChild(html); // insere no body
```

Após isso, você irá buscar dentro dessa nova div inserida alguma tag `script`:

```
var scripts = html.querySelectorAll("script");
```

E verificar se existe com um `if`:

```
if(scripts.length){
}
```

Se existir o `scripts.length` irá retornar um valor maior que `0`. Dentro do `if` você faz um laço concatenando numa variável todo o conteúdo das tags `script` existentes e ao mesmo tempo removendo-as do DOM, para depois inserir uma nova tag `script` no `body` com o conteúdo concatenado:

```
if(scripts.length){
  var codigos = '';
   for(var sc = 0; sc < scripts.length; sc++){
      codigos += scripts[sc].innerHTML;
      scripts[sc].outerHTML = ''; // remove do DOM
   }
   script = document.createElement("script");
   script.innerHTML = codigos;
   el.appendChild(script);
}
```

Desta forma a página terá uma nova tag `script` com todo o código do (ou dos) `script` retornado pelo AJAX e estará carregada na memória do JavaScript para ser executada. Veja o código completo:

```
url = 'https://meusite.com/widget.php';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) { 
        var resp = this.response;
        var el = document.querySelector('body');
        var html = document.createElement("div");
        html.innerHTML = resp;
        el.appendChild(html);
        var scripts = html.querySelectorAll("script");
        if(scripts.length){
           var codigos = '';
            for(var sc = 0; sc < scripts.length; sc++){
               codigos += scripts[sc].innerHTML;
               scripts[sc].outerHTML = '';
            }
            script = document.createElement("script");
            script.innerHTML = codigos;
            el.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
```

Repare que usei `el.appendChild(html);` para inserir a div com o retorno do AJAX no final do `body`, mas você poderia usar também o método `.insertAdjacentHTML()` da seguinte forma:

```
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo auxílio e explicação, @sam! Funcionou que é uma beleza! Abraços!